# Empty text box - way to return error or block button

Tags: c#, winforms

I have been trying to fix my triangle calculator but I have no idea how and been looking through this forum for some time now.

I got issue with empty boxes. When I fill 3rd box leaving 2 empty it crashes but if I start from 1st it return error as normal. I have tried many different ways but still couldn't figure it out. I just need to

```
if (textBox1.Text == string.Empty)
{

    errorProvider1.SetError(textBox1, "Enter value");

}
if (textBox2.Text == string.Empty)
{

    errorProvider2.SetError(textBox2, "Enter value");

}
if (textBox3.Text == string.Empty)
{
    errorProvider3.SetError(textBox3, "Enter value");
    return;
}
```

@Edit

Sorry.

I got simple form program that calculate triangle area, perimeter etc.
Whenever there is empty text box program will crash. I'm looking for way to handle those empty boxes.

So far I manage to handle all three boxes but whenever there is input in it crash.

Comment: Your question is not clear on what you are looking for. Please describe more precisely otherwise we will not able to help you.

Comment: your return should outside if

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it is breaking is that the 3rd condition is true and so it will not go into 3rd if block. So `return` there will not be executed and hence all the statements below `if` conditions will be executed. You need to add `return` inside every if condition so that even if 1 fails, it will break the loop.

```
        if (textBox1.Text == string.Empty)
        {
            errorProvider1.SetError(textBox1, "Enter value");
            return;
        }
        if (textBox2.Text == string.Empty)
        {
            errorProvider2.SetError(textBox2, "Enter value");
            return;
        }
        if (textBox3.Text == string.Empty)
        {
            errorProvider3.SetError(textBox3, "Enter value");
            return;
        }
```

If you want to display all 3 messages, then you can add another check to see if any of the text boxes is null and return from there.

```
    if (textBox1.Text == string.Empty)
    {
        errorProvider1.SetError(textBox1, "Enter value");
    }
    if (textBox2.Text == string.Empty)
    {
        errorProvider2.SetError(textBox2, "Enter value");
    }
    if (textBox3.Text == string.Empty)
    {
        errorProvider3.SetError(textBox3, "Enter value");
    }

    if(textBox1.Text == string.Empty || textBox1.Text == string.Empty || textBox3.Text == string.Empty)
    {
        return;
    }
```